# Blazor InputFile onchange doesn't trigger the method

Tags: .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-8.0

```
@page "/fileup"
<h3>FileUp</h3>
<InputFile OnChange="@UploadedExcel" accept=".xlsx" />
@code {
    public async Task UploadedExcel(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        
    }
}
```

The code should be basic enough but it doesn't trigger the task down below when I upload a file. Am I missing something?

I have tried a few different things including changing to multifile and all. I have another page with full code block that I don't wanna sahre because of many unrelated things. But this on itself should work right?
[Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkEXg.png)

I was missing the @rendermode InteractiveAuto at the top of the page. After adding it, it triggered my method.

Answer (score 1):

It does work, however there seems to be a misunderstanding on your end.

I am assuming that you think the code does not get executed because you don't see a `Hello` printed in your console, when you run the app with `dotnet run` or `dotnet watch` or within your preferred IDE. And yes, nothing will be printed there, but that's absolutely expected.

If you have a Blazor WebAssembly app the `UploadedExcel()` method is going to run on the client-side in the browser, which means the `Console.WriteLine("Hello")` will print to the browser console, not the console/ terminal on the server side.

Check your browser console (Open Developer tools -> Choose Tab `Console`) and you will see `Hello` getting printed.

Comment: I use browser console to check. Also I put that there only for breakpoint purposes. It doesn't get triggered at all.

Comment: Then there seems to be some issue with your setup. I've tested your code on my Blazor WebAssembly app and it runs as expected. Are you sure you're using WebAssembly? Does the .NET Runtime (compiled to WebAssembly) get downloaded when you load the site (check `Networks` tab)? If not be sure to configure your project correctly.

Comment: I am using Server and WebAssembly. I shared the networks screenshot as a reference.

Comment: From the screenshot It looks like you only have a WebSocket connection (might be Blazor Server or just the debugging connection to the browser). When you have Blazor WebAssembly you should see a lot of `.dll` files being downloaded in the browser tab. Do you have the [rendermodes properly configured](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0#apply-a-render-mode-to-a-component-definition)?

Comment: Just got it to trigger I was missing the @rendermode InteractiveAuto